# I want to capture screen of my iPhone (video call)

Tags: iphone, quicktime, screen-capture

I want to capture screen of my iPhone (video call). When i use quicktime, i get this horrible echo, so i can't listen to the call and record it simultaneously. Is there any way to overcome this echo?

Comment: May be to use headphones?

Answer (score 3):

iOS 11 includes a [built-in Screen Recording function](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-ios-11-built-in-screen-recording-feature/), which also includes an option to turn the microphone on during the session, by long-pressing or hard-pressing the screen recording button.

[image]

You might want to try that.